# Swift - expected '{' to start setter definition

Tags: swift

I'm following the advanced swift WWDC 2014 video, using a subscript on a class to delegate down to a class property but I'm getting an error using the same syntax as in the video

```
enum Direction {
    case North, South, East, West
}

class Place: Thing {
    init (_ location: Thing?, _ name: String, _ longDescription: String) {
        self.exits = Dictionary<Direction, Place> ()
        super.init(location, name, longDescription)
    }
    var exits: Dictionary<Direction, Place>
}

extension Place {
    subscript(direction: Direction) -> Place? {
        get {
            return exits[direction]
        }
        set (destination: Place?) { // error here
            exits[direction] = destination
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Expected '{' to start setter definition
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omit the type in your setter, it's inferred automatically:

```
subscript(direction: Direction) -> Place? {
    get {
        return exits[direction]
    }
    set (destination) {
        exits[direction] = destination
    }
}
```

You can also skip the parameter altogether, in that case it's implicitly named `newValue`:

```
subscript(direction: Direction) -> Place? {
    get {
        return exits[direction]
    }
    set {
        exits[direction] = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. “The type of `newValue` is the same as the return value of the subscript” is the line in The Swift Programming Language book that specifies this (`newValue` in the example in the book is the setter's parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass on a parameter to set

```
set  { 
    exits[direction] = newValue
}
```